# Need help with holomorphic functions on a domain interval removed.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that for a region $\Omega$ with interval $I=[a,b]\subset\Omega$, if $f$ is continuous in $\Omega$ and $f\in H(\Omega-I)$, then actually $f\in H(\Omega)$.

Is this problem related to the removable singularity?
and are there some other sets that could draw same conclusion?

Comment: This is related to something called (continuous) analytic capacity. If there is no answer, I'll post something when I have more time.

Comment: One can use continuity to show that every integral of $f$ along a closed trigonal contour vanishes (wherever one crosses $[a,b]$--which happens at most twice--instead go around it, with opposite directions very nearly canceling each other out).

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070951) for something very similar.